# Which Ruby on Rails active record model method can be used to look for a particular value in the model's column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Let's say I have a model, `Animal`, and a column, `animal_name`. When a user enter chicken, I want to check in the Animal model if there is `animal_name` "chicken". Assuming the `@animal` variable carries a value that user entered, how do I check that value exists in the `animal_name` column?

```
def check_animal
    if @animal......... #Exists in Animal model
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one of these two forms:

- `Animal.find_by_name("chicken")`
- `Animal.where(:name => "chicken")`

Or using a variable:

- `Animal.find_by_name(@animal_name)`
- `Animal.where(:name => @animal_name)`

See:

- *[Ruby on Rails 3.0 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html)*
- *[Active Record Query Interface 3.0](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface)*

Comment: wheni do that it tells me `undefined method `find_by_name' for #<Class:0xbd6a2f8>`

Comment: if you use 'animal_name' as the attribute, then it should be find_by_animal_name